# User or role does not exist in this database

Tags: windows, sql-server, active-directory, sql-server-2005

I am trying to add a new login in SQL Server 2005. I can go into the security properties for the database in SQL Management Studio, and I can select a domain user, but when I click OK to close out of the security properties page SQL tells me it can't find the domain user I'm trying to add. It does let me add the domain administrator account as a SQL login, but that's the only one that works. Any ideas on how I can solve this issue?

This is on a virtual machine hosted on server 2008. I recently reinstalled my domain controller (which isn't a production dc, it's just for testing purposes) and this vm was created in the previous domain. Not sure if that has anything to do with this or not, but it's suspicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you "reinstalled the domain controller" you mean you created a new domain in a new forest?  or you added a new DC to the existing domain?

My guess here is that you have the sql server in a domain that no longer exists.  You will need to remove the server from the previous domain & join it to the new one, before you can access any of the domain objects for sql server permissions.

Comment: Ah, makes total sense. Should have thought of that. Just tried it and worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You first have to add the account at the server level before you can add it at the database level.  It's probably letting you add the domain administrator account because, by default, the builtin\administrators machine local group is added to the server with sysadmin privileges and the domain admin account is typically a member of that machine local group.

In SQL Server Management Studio, within Object Explorer, expand Security, right-click on Logins and choose New Login and enter the info for the new login.  After that is done you should be able to add that login to your database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's actually the exact thing I'm trying to do and I can't because sql server tells me it can't find the domain account (even though I can select it!).